# Not able to execute post request using node js ,mysql and sequelize library

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am making api for simple Todo App using node.js, Mysql and [Sequelize ORM Library](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) . Basically there are 2 tables Todos and TodoItems. The relationship between these two tables are

1) A Todo can have many TodoItems .
2) A TodoItem can have only one TodoId.

so according to second relationship I am making a foreign key in TodoItems Table and making a post request for the entering a TodoItem in the TodoItems table.

This is my controller function for creating and entering todoitem in the table

```
const TodoItem = require('../models').TodoItem;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {

    console.log(req.params.todo_id)
    return TodoItem
      .create({
        content: req.body.content,
        todoId: req.params.todo_id,

      })
      .then(todoItem => res.status(201).send(todoItem))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

and this is my migration file for creating TodoItems table

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('TodoItems', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      complete: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },

      todoId:{

        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        allowNull:false,

        references:{

          model:'Todos',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'todoId',
        }

      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('TodoItems');
  }
};
```

and the router function for the same is

```
var express = require ('express');
var router = express.Router();
var model = require('../models/index');
var db = require('../models');
const todosItemsController = require('../controllers').todoItems;


router.post('/:todo_id', todosItemsController.create);


module.exports = router;
```

so the api link is somewhat like this

localhost:4006/todoitems/1

But when I am running this api in postman for testing it is giving this error

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "code": "ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD",
        "errno": 1364,
        "sqlState": "HY000",
        "sqlMessage": "Field 'todoId' doesn't have a default value",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `TodoItems` (`id`,`content`,`complete`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'first todo item inside first todo',false,'2018-02-08 14:38:10','2018-02-08 14:38:10');"
    },
    "original": {
        "code": "ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD",
        "errno": 1364,
        "sqlState": "HY000",
        "sqlMessage": "Field 'todoId' doesn't have a default value",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `TodoItems` (`id`,`content`,`complete`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'first todo item inside first todo',false,'2018-02-08 14:38:10','2018-02-08 14:38:10');"
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `TodoItems` (`id`,`content`,`complete`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'first todo item inside first todo',false,'2018-02-08 14:38:10','2018-02-08 14:38:10');"
}
```

Since I have made validated the todoId not null so it cannot take a null value but I am passing todoId in the api link and I have also written code which should fetch todoId from the api link and assign that value to todoId column in the table.

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error .
One thing more I am not able to understand when I am having todoId column also in the TodoItems but in the error I am able to see all columns of TodoItem table but not TodoId as it is written

"INSERT INTO `TodoItems` (`id`,`content`,`complete`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`)".

Why that TodoId column is missing . I am not able to understand

Please help Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the documentation properly and that is why I have not declared

todoId: {
  type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: 'todo',
    key: 'id'
  }
},
 in the todoItems model